# Как добавить html в динамически построенный элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть динамически строящийся список по ajax-запросу при загрузке страницы:

```
function showItems()
        {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'Post',
                url: 'url',
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    let itemsArray = $.parseJSON(response);
                    let output = '';
                    for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
                        output += '<div class="link">' + itemsArray[i] +
                            '</div><ul class="submenu"></ul>';
                    }
                    $('#accordion').empty().append(output);
                }
            });
        }
```

HTML-разметка до загрузки страницы:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <ul id="accordion" class="accordion"></ul>
</aside>
```

И после:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
        <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[0]</div>
                    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[1]</div>
                    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[2]</div>
                    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
              </li>
              ...
        </ul>
</aside>
```

По клику на пункты этого списка опять же ajax-запросом получаю пункты вложенного списка, которые нужно вставить в динамически отстроенный в предыдущей функции элемент ul class="submenu"

```
function showSubitems()
                {
                    $('#accordion').on('click','.link',function(){
                        console.log($(this)); // n.fn.init [div.link, context: div.link]
                        let request = $(this).prop('textContent');
                        console.log(request); // item - текстовый контент пункта меню, то что нужно
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'Post',
                            url: 'url',
                            data: {'data': request},
                            success: function(response) {
                                let subitemsArray = $.parseJSON(response);
                                let output = '';
                                for (let i = 0; i < subitemsArray.length; i++) {
                                    output += '<li><a href="#">' + subitemsArray[i] + '</a></li>';
                                }
                                console.log(output); // <li><a href="#">subitem[0]</a></li><li><a href="#">subitem[1]</a></li>
                                $(this).next('.submenu').append(output);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                }
```

HTML-разметка, которая должна получиться:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
        <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[0]</div> // На этом пункте был клик
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">subitem[0]</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subitem[1]</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">subitem[2]</a></li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[1]</div>
                    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                    <div class="link">Item[2]</div>
                    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
              </li>
              ...
        </ul>
</aside>
```

Так вот последняя до скобок строчка во второй функции $(this).next('.submenu').append(output); не работает.. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать, чтоб заработало?

Comment: скорее всего потому, что `$(this).` в `success` указывает уже не на элемент. у него контекст уже сменился на контекст функции. Раньше делали так: до блока, где может смениться контекст писали `var $this = $(this);`. И уже эту переменную потом применяли

Comment: Сергей Мишин, спасибо за ответ.. попробовал Ваш вариант - не сработал. Добавил логи консоли, чтоб было понятнее, что происходит(что я вижу) по ходу выполнения 2й функции.

Comment: лучше добавьте html разметку

Comment: Добавил html-разметку.

Comment: `$(document).find(this).next('.submenu').append(output);` попробуйте так

Comment: @Денис , спасибо за участие.. попробовал - не помогло. В консоли всё то же самое

Comment: @СергейМишин , вы были правы - дело $(this) в последней строке.. воткнул перед этой строкой console.log($(this)); , а там уже функция. Как надо, пока не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` изменяется в зависимости от контекста выполнения функции

В функции `success` он отличен от того, что в функции, которая обрабатывает событие

Варианты решения

1. Использовать стрелочную функцию с `ES6`, заменить `success: function(response) {` на `success: (response) => {`
2. Сохранить `this`, в начале функции, которая обрабатывает событие, добавить `var self = this;` и заменить `$(this).next('.submenu').append(output);` на `$(self).next('.submenu').append(output);`
3. Привязать контекст функции, с помощью `Function​.prototype​.bind`, обвернуть код функции `success` так - `success: (function(response) {
   ...
   }).bind(this)`

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за ответ. Пробовал 2й вариант вчера, а 3й сейчас - console.log($(this)); перед последней строкой, внутри success, выдаёт необходимый элемент div.link, но подменю всё равно не добавляется в DOM. Ищу ошибку..

Answer (score 0):

Все ответы оказались верными: в коде была проблема в this внутри success. Всем спасибо.
Причиной же того, что не получаю необходимый результат - не раскрывается подменю по клику на пункт меню - оказалось то, что css-стили на динамических элементах(.submenu ...) не отрабатывают так же, как на статических. Элементы же(пункты подменю) по клику в DOM-дерево добавляются, но у ul.submenu display остаётся none.